# Console Application VB, Need help when displaying answers on all one page

Tags: vb.net, console-application

What would i have to input in this code to get the answers displayed in the stock order part of the program, if i put console.writeline(sale) there then on one thing shows even if i have inputted multiple things for sale, so how do i save the previous transaction to show at the end i.e the stock order part, i think it's something to do with counter but now basically need to know how to save previous inputted information to show at the end.

Sub Main()

```
    Dim start As String
    Dim Sale As String
    Dim Receipt As String
    Dim endProgram As String
    Dim StockOrder As New list(Of String)



    Console.WriteLine("Welcome, Let's start today's sales")
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("please type 'Yes' or 'No', Yes to Start and No to Stop")
    start = Console.ReadLine()

    Do
        If (start = "Yes") Then
            Console.WriteLine("What have you sold today? and for how much? and Please input Code on the side of the item")
            Sale = Console.ReadLine
            StockOrder.Add(Console.ReadLine)


            Console.Clear()
            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Customer Receipt")
            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.WriteLine(Sale)
            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Dear customer thank you for shopping with us, we appreciated your custom. please note that we have a 14 day return policy in which you can return faulty or unused and unopened items, if any product is returned without any fault please know that a 25% handling fee may apply, for any repair you have a three month warranty, this warranty only includes fault with the item replaced and any additional faults that occur will not be our responsibility.")
            Receipt = Console.ReadLine

            Console.Clear()
            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Would You Like to Continue?")
            start = Console.ReadLine

            If (start = "No") Then
                Console.Clear()
                Console.WriteLine("Stock Order and Sales Sheet")
                Console.WriteLine()


                Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, StockOrder))

                For i = 0 To StockOrder.Count - 1
                    Console.WriteLine(StockOrder(i))
                Next

            End If

        ElseIf (start = "No") Then

            Console.WriteLine("Since you don't want to use the program nothing else will be ordered in the stock order")

            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using this program")
            endProgram = Console.ReadLine
            End
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: What is it that you're asking? Additionally, the code won't compile; `StockOrder = `. What is the value of `StockOrder`?

Comment: What is the datatype of `Sale`

Comment: stock order has no value, when i run the program without the stock order it runs fine the only problem i have is saving previously inputted info into a single page, so if i have multiple sales, i only get the stock order for the most recent thing i inputted i need it to be added for everything i have added,

Comment: sale is string, since i add what i sold and price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a string list for the stock orders, which can store multiple strings and also keeps track of how many strings are stored.

```
Dim stockList As New List(Of String) 'initialize empty string list

stockList.Add(console.ReadLine) 'adds to the end of the list

For i = 0 To stockList.Count - 1 'print out all entries in the list
     console.WriteLine(stockList(i))
Next
```

Comment: this semi work, instead if inputting what i wrote it inputs

"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"

Do you know why? Thanks though improved slightly :)

Comment: I think it should be i = 0 To stockList.Count - 1. Because the list's indexes begins at 0, so there is nothing in the location of stockList(stockList.Count)

Comment: Also, make sure you have "console.WriteLine(stockList(i))" not "console.WriteLine(stockList)". i is the index of the string in the list.

Comment: Getting the same problem, im guessing its not printing what's in the list and i dont know how to display whats in the list

Comment: if i dont have the for next loop then it requires i requires a variable, should i make it an integer? when i have console.WriteLine(stockList(i)) i dont get anything back, when i take (i) out i get the first message

Comment: just added everything

Comment: I think there's a problem in these two lines: Sale = Console.ReadLine
            StockOrder.Add(Console.ReadLine) because you are reading from the console twice? First you are setting sale = console input and then adding the next console input to stockOrder. I'm not sure if that's what you want to do. Also there is nothing happening to the receipt. Do you need to store that?

Comment: I think that you want to do Sale = Console.ReadLine StockOrder.Add(Sale). That way you are adding the stored input string.

Comment: so i need sale to make a receipt, you're right i dont need to store it. so i can remove that. and the problem was that i had sale = console.readline, didnt need that. i appreciate the help. making this for the dissertation so needed a viable program haha once again thank you

Comment: No problem, if I answered your question please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers